# regular expression exclude match that contains a string pattern

Tags: regex

I'm trying to narrow down my RegEx to ignore form elements with `type="submit"`. I only want to select the portion of elements up to the part `class="*"` but still ignore if type="submit" comes before or after the class.

My regular expression thus far:

```
(<(?:input|select|textarea){1}.*[^type="submit"]class=")(((?!form\-control)[a-zA-Z0-9_ -])*")
```

Test case:
Line one should match up to the end of class, and line 2 ignored.

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="test" class="example-class" max-length="7" required="required">
<input type="submit" class="btn-primary" value="send">
```

Is this acheivable?

Comment: What language are you using this regex in?

Comment: I'm using the atom text editor search and replace tool to perform batch html changes. It's not part of a script. I'm using http://regexr.com/ to build the regex

Comment: WHY are so many people use `...{1}` what do you think this will change?

Comment: AND `[...]` is not for entire strings!

Comment: you will need something with negative look ahead! http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've added an answer, feel free to point out any obvious flaws with the negative look ahead I've used.

Comment: Obligatory link: [You cannot parse \[X\]HTML with RegEx.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1072112)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments. The answer was a negative look ahead.

Adding `(?!.*type="submit.*)` to the start of the regex appears to have given me my desired result.

**Working Regex:**

```
(?!.*type="submit.*)(<(?:input|select|textarea).*class=")(((?!form\-control)[a-zA-Z0-9_ -])*")
```

Comment: We still think a program that uses a valid HTML parser would make more sense

Comment: I'm not sure why a HTML parser keeps getting referenced. I want to perform a project wide search and replace of multiple HTML files using a regular expression pattern. Is a HTML parser still relevant for this scenario?

Comment: Absolutely. You can write a small script in any language to search over many files in a folder. It just depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
(<(?:input|select|textarea)\s((?!type="submit")[\w\-]+\b="[^"]*"\s?)*>)
```

This expression is bound to the single tag.
It is better to avoid expressions like `.*` since it can go further and match a string which would begin inside one tag and end-up inside another.